# flex3 datagrid horizontal alignment

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex3

i cant find a way to horizontal alignment of the data grid rows, although it has a vertical alignment parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like [DataGridColumn's textAlign Style](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#style:textAlign)?

```
<mx:DataGrid>
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" textAlign="left"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" textAlign="center"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 3" textAlign="right"/>
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: i have an item renderer in each dataGridColumn and rows have CheckBoxes... the check boxes are always at left... do i have to contain them with an hbox and then use horizontal alighn???

Comment: Yes. That's what I would do too.